# HTML/CSS Need help getting my anchors to be the same size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my anchors to be the same size, but since the texts are different length, the padding distance is different. I end up getting different sized squares.

```css
.roles{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 90%;
}

.roles h3{
  width: 22%;
  margin: 0px 4%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.roles h3 a{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class = "roles">
      <h3><a href = "roles\president.html"> President </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\vicePresident.html"> Vice President </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\secretary.html"> Secretary </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\treasurer.html"> Treasurer </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\pledgeMaster.html"> Pledge Master(s) [PM] </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\socialChair.html"> Social Chair </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\housingChair.html"> Housing Chair </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\academicChair.html"> Academic Chair </a></h3>
      <h3><a href = "roles\committeeChair.html"> Committee Chair </a></h3>
    </div>
```

This is my HTML and CSS code. How should I change it without going into each one and manually inputting it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `inline-flex` you can achieve what you are looking for. I had to make some changes to your code though. I changed the `h3` for `div`, since it is more common to have elements inside a `div` or a `span` than `h3`. I moved the padding and the border to the `div`, because otherwise it would be quite hard to fit the needed spaces. You can learn more about the flexbox layout in the following [page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.roles{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.roles div{
  width: 25%;
  color: #666;
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.roles div a{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "roles">
      <div><a href = "roles\president.html"> President </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\vicePresident.html"> Vice President </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\secretary.html"> Secretary </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\treasurer.html"> Treasurer </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\pledgeMaster.html"> Pledge Master(s) [PM] </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\socialChair.html"> Social Chair </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\housingChair.html"> Housing Chair </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\academicChair.html"> Academic Chair </a></div>
      <div><a href = "roles\committeeChair.html"> Committee Chair </a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. I'm gonna take a look at that page now.

Comment: You're welcome @ashbum! Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: I think that I marked it as the right answer. Sorry if I didn't. Kinda new to this.